# createTable first, then putItem into table that just created

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

With using the API version of '2012-08-10', I'm trying to create a table on DynamoDB. My Lambda code acquiring `groupID` via API. Once the table is created, as a follow up I'm trying to add the first item to the table as follows:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: 'eu-central-1' });
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var itemParams = {
        ...some itemParams
    });

    var tableParams = {
        ...some tableParams
    };

    dynamodb.createTable(tableParams, function (err, data) {
        if (err) { console.log(err, err.stack) }
        else { console.log("Table created", data); }
    });

    dynamodb.putItem(itemParams, function (err, data) {
        if (err) callback(null, err);
        else callback(null, data);
    });
};
```

Unfortunately I'm receiving a "ResourceNotFoundException" error. Basically putItem doesn't recognize the table just created. Any suggestions on how to create a trigger here? Is there a way to putItem to the table that is just created? Thank you!

Also in case you are wondering the details of params:

```
var tableParams = {
    AttributeDefinitions: [
        {
            AttributeName: "memberID",
            AttributeType: "S"
        }
    ],
    KeySchema: [
        {
            AttributeName: "memberID",
            KeyType: "HASH"
        }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
        ReadCapacityUnits: 2,
        WriteCapacityUnits: 2
    },
    TableName: "plexiGr_" + event.groupID
};

var itemParams = {
    TableName: "plexiGr_" + event.groupID,
    Item: {
        "memberID": { S: event.groupAdmin },
        "memberName": { S: "Julius" },
        "memberAge": { N: "32" }
    },
    ConditionExpression: "attribute_not_exists(groupID)"
};
```

Comment: Please format your code properly with proper intend etc.

Answer (score 1):

The DynamoDB `CreateTable` operation is *asynchronous* - it just **starts** to create a table, but returns before the table's creation is finished. The [CreateTable document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTable.html) explains that:

> `CreateTable` is an asynchronous operation. Upon receiving a `CreateTable` request, DynamoDB immediately returns a response with a `TableStatus` of `CREATING`. After the table is created, DynamoDB sets the `TableStatus` to `ACTIVE`. You can perform read and write operations only on an ACTIVE table.

In other words, when `CreateTable` completes, the table is not yet usable: You now need to do a loop of `DescribeTable`, waiting until the table's status has become `ACTIVE`. Only then you can use the table.

Because this is a useful loop, most AWS libraries have a function to automate it. I'm familar with the Python one in the boto3 library, but I assume nodejs also has a similar one. Or you can just call `DescribeTable` yourself.

To reiterate, despite what other responses said, it is *not* enough to wait for `CreateTable` to complete. It will complete much earlier than you can really use the table. You must also wait, separately, for the new table's status to change to `ACTIVE`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not waiting until your table is created. The commands for creating the table and putting an item in it are run in sequence but without waiting for the callbacks.

So either you put the code to write the item into the callback of the create table action or you use promises to wait until the table is created.

```js
dynamodb.createTable(tableParams, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
        return;
    }

    dynamodb.putItem(itemParams, function(putItemErr, putItemData) {
        if (putItemErr) callback(null, putItemErr);
        else            callback(null, putItemData);
    });
});
```

Using promises:

```js
await dynamodb.createTable(tableParams).promise();
await dynamodb.putItem(itemParams).promise();
```

Comment: Jens thank you so much for your quick response. I actually do use callback in my function. To make it clear I updated my original question and added parameters of exports.handler. Yet trying your solution it still provides a "ResourceNotFoundException". What do you think I'm making wrong? Do you want to see parameter objects in details?

Comment: @kk651 please read the code I wrote carefully. You are not doing it like I do in my snippet and it would probably fix your issue.

Comment: I tried once again, went through your code, besides tried c/p but unfortunately it didn't work. do you think it relies to the apiVersion? do you suggest any resource for me to learn more regarding async/await in lambda? Thank you for all the advice!